# Drupal is extremely slow handling simple AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax, performance, drupal

I wrote a simple AJAX callback function in Drupal that performs a query to the DB and returns a JSON formatted string. Nothing fancy, the standard AJAX declaration in the module with a modest amount of information (less than 4KB). The query to the database takes 52ms. Drupal adds around 320ms of overhead for a total of 370ms + latency. And that in my development machine (only one user)...

Is this normal? Do you know how you can decrease that huge overhead?

Context:
- Clean install
- No extra modules
- Without the Drupal cache. I want to know the real performance of Drupal (I'm starting to be really concerned about how slow this is - I didn't expect it).
- APC opcode cache activated

Thanks in advance,
Juan

P.D.: At some point I was wondering what'd be the real effect of no having a connection pool to the DB like Java frameworks, and running the whole PHP script every time. Maybe I'm starting to see the performance problems of using PHP?

Comment: Do you have MySQL's query caching on? PHP's APC opcode cache? How many modules do you have enabled?

Comment: This was the very first thing I noticed about Drupal.. it's slow. Very, very slow.

Comment: @jnpcl In inexperienced hands, it can be. With a properly configured server, appropriate performance and caching settings, etc. you can have a nice fast Drupal install. Hell, it's good enough for WhiteHouse.gov and The Economist.

Comment: @jnpcl you haven't tried ezPublish yet I suppose :p
Anyway the french gouvernement has got Drupal installation. It runs very well and it's not just news, but also videos (I worked on this project for almost 2 years)

Comment: @ceejayoz: All I did was install.. no custom theme, no addons. Zero content pages, 1 user. Changing between pages just felt sluggish to me. YSlow was showing 3-4 seconds for almost every page.  I tried out a basic WordPress install on the same system, and those pages loaded in 0.5-1.0 seconds.

Comment: Drupal's more complex than WordPress, but 3-4 seconds for a stock install sounds very odd. If you install the Devel module, it has options that allow you to figure out which queries are slowing down the page. Might be worth testing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [js](http://drupal.org/project/js) module to handle your ajax requests. You can specify only really necessary modules and includes required for you callback. It helps save about 30-70% time for your requests and even more, if you use cache to store processed data.